# How to set video size of MediaRecorder to fill perfectly to width and height of device screen?

Tags: android, video, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

I record video using `MediaRecorder` in a `SurfaceView`,once done recording,I pass to another activity to preview the video.I want the video capture is fit perfectly to device screen

I tried to set video size when prepare recorder:

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

//# Video settings
mRecorder.setVideoSize(width,height);
```

I also set the camera parameter in surfaceCreated() as well:

```
mCamera = Camera.open();
Camera.Parameters parameters;
parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
parameters.setPreviewSize(width,height);
mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
```

Once done recording,I pass the video captured to another activity,and set into a `VideoView`,the `VideoView` layout already set to `MATCH_PARENT` for width and height already.

```
videoPreview = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoPreview);
videoPreview.setVideoURI(videoUri);
videoPreview.start();
```

Although I set the video size and camera parameters,but the video capture still not as big as the device screen.I using Pixel XL emulator,the width is fit the screen,but the height is only half of the screen.

So my question is,how to capture a video that will fit perfectly to width and height of every screen using `MediaRecorder`?

Comment: What did you end up with?

Answer (score 0):

This is my method to fit video with screen :

when init params of the camera do this code :

```
     Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
                        preferredSize = params.getPreferredPreviewSizeForVideo();
                        adaptPrefferedVideoSize(params);
                        params.setPreviewSize(preferredSize.width, preferredSize.height);

adjustVideoSurface(screenWidth, screenHeight,preferredSize.width, preferredSize.height, surfaceView);
    //...
```

and this the the adaptPrefferedVideoSize method :

```
 public void adaptPrefferedVideoSize(Camera.Parameters params) {

        Camera.Size sizeW640 = params.getPreviewSize();
        Camera.Size sizeW720 = params.getPreviewSize();
        Camera.Size sizeW1280 = params.getPreviewSize();

        sizeW640.width = 640;
        sizeW640.height = 480;

        sizeW720.width = 720;
        sizeW720.height = 480;

        sizeW1280.width = 1280;
        sizeW1280.height = 720;

        preferredSize = sizeW1280;

        /*************************/
        if (params.getSupportedVideoSizes() != null) {
            if (params.getSupportedVideoSizes().contains(sizeW1280)) {
                preferredSize = sizeW1280;
            } else if (params.getSupportedVideoSizes().contains(sizeW720)) {
                preferredSize = sizeW720;
            } else {
                preferredSize = sizeW640;
            }
        } else if (preferredSize != null) {
            if (preferredSize.width > sizeW1280.width) {
                preferredSize = sizeW1280;
            } else if (!preferredSize.equals(sizeW720)) {
                preferredSize = sizeW640;
            }
        } else {
            preferredSize = sizeW640;
        }
    }
```

and This is adjustVideoSurface method :

```
public static boolean adjustVideoSurface(int screenWidth,
                                             int screenHeight,
                                             int width,
                                             int height,
                                             SurfaceView surfaceView) {


        int preferredWidth = (width < height) ? width : height;
        int preferredHeight = (width < height) ? height : width;

        float ratioW = (float) screenWidth / preferredWidth;
        float ratioH = (float) screenHeight / preferredHeight;
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;


        int displayedHeight = (int) (ratioW * preferredHeight);
        int displayedWidth = (int) (ratioH * preferredWidth);

        layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(screenWidth, displayedHeight);

        if (displayedHeight > screenHeight) {
            layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(displayedWidth, screenHeight);
        }

        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
        surfaceView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        surfaceView.requestLayout();


        return Math.round(ratioH - ratioW) == 0;
    }
```

I hope that this coul help you.

Comment: is it width and height I state it myself?and screenwidth and screenHeight is taken by displayMetric?

Comment: this method `getPreferredPreviewSizeForVideo();` how to define?can u state it out as well? thanks

Comment: getPreferredPreviewSizeForVideo is a method defined in   Camera.Parameters . 

Yes screenwidth and screenHeight are  taken by displayMetric 

and the width and heigh are corresponding to the preferredSize.width and preferredSize.height as mentioned above .

Comment: Do you use Camera 1 or Camera 2 ?

Comment: I use Camera1 bro

Comment: So params.getPreferredPreviewSizeForVideo is valid , you can find it. 
Please try the code above and tell me what it gives you ?

Comment: ok..Later I will try your code..any result I let you know..thanks

Comment: Sir I found a problem..`layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);` this line,cause I using `FrameLayout`,cannot use Relative Layout,any other ways?

Comment: You can just replace each word RelativeLayout by FrameLayout

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is,how to capture a video that will fit perfectly to width and height of every screen using MediaRecorder?

That is not possible.

First, there is no requirement that the device's camera(s) support a resolution that is equal to the physical resolution of the screen.

Second, your UI may not be taking up the full screen anyway (e.g., exists in a floating window in a freeform multi-window device).

Comment: I mean the capture a video that same height and width with preview in SurfaceView.What I see in SurfaceView,the video is appear exactly same width and height with the SurfaceView..By the way my SurfaceView is match_parent..is it possible to do that??

Comment: @ CommonsWare. Hi can you help me for my question ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/46790086/4813855   Thanks a lot

Comment: @ken: "I mean the capture a video that same height and width with preview in SurfaceView" -- that is not possible. A `SurfaceView` can have any resolution; your camera cannot support arbitrary resolutions.

Comment: @CommonsWare same height and width with device is it possible?

Comment: @ken: No, because there is no requirement for the camera to support an identical resolution to the screen resolution. It *might* support that resolution. It might not.